# Problem with selection tool z-painting ( red brush)

Tags: meshlab

I am working on a 3d model of skull, and I want to isolate the canine tooth but the thing is whenever I am selection the tooth using the red brush in z-painting, my selection go trough the the tooth and select a the same time other particules that I don't want. Is there a way  to limit the selection to a specific area without it going trough the model ?

I tried different type of filter to maybe correct that problem but I wasn't able to find a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pressing key Alt key while drawing the selection rectangle will only select the faces that are visible.